# Android sdk manager not showing up ( Ubuntu )

Tags: eclipse

I am currently using ubuntu 12.10, to begin with android i downloaded the ADT bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html, it contains eclipse and all other supporting libraries in itself so all i have to do is click the eclipse icon twice and it starts working.

After launching eclipse , everytime in click on the SDK manager it shows a popup with progress bar and then disappears.

Does anyone else had the same issue or if someone can guide me the right way

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ok i figured out the problem , in order to make adt bundle work i need to install Java 6 instead of 7 so the below command worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```